# Удалить ссылку с атрибутом title и добавить класс родительскому li

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Есть меню вида:

```
<ul id="menu-primary-1" class="nav navbar-nav center">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6">
        <a href="/" title="Главная">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8">
        <a href="#" title="divider">divider</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-7 active">
        <a href="http://test2/2016/07/24/page/" title="page">page</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Как сделать чтобы удалялась ссылка с `title="divider"` и `href="#"`, а ее родительскому `<li>` добавлялся класс `.active`. При этом все остальное чтобы так и оставалось.

```
window.onload=function(){
    var o=document.querySelector('a[title="divider"]');
    o.parentNode.removeChild(o);
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('divider');
};
```

Этим ничего не получилось((
Кстати да, если это так важно то меню генерится wordpress-ом.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <span class="navbar-brand">МЕНЮ</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                                <?php /* Primary navigation */
                                wp_nav_menu( array(
                                    'menu' => 'primary',
                                    'depth' =>  2,
                                    'container' => false,
                                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav center',
                                    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                                    //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                                );
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
```

На выходе же мы имеем меню в том виде которое написано выше.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload=function(){
    $('a[title="divider"]').parent().addClass('active');
    $('a[title="divider"]').hide();  
};
```

Comment: К сожалению почему-то ни первое ни второе не работает((

Comment: @seledkapod какой именно результат вы хотите видеть?

Comment: выше более детально описал проблему, я не спорю в html ваш код работает на ура, но на вордпресс воз и ныне там.

Comment: возможно js срабатывает раньше, чем загружается ваш nav ?

Comment: @C.Raf.T, а как же `window.onload`?

Comment: @Doofy а может подгружается динамически??

Comment: Скрипт тупо добавил в header.php в самый конец.

Comment: также пробовал его в common.js свой дописать, та же проблема((

Comment: В общем все равно спасибо, просто это не js проблема, а видимо WP + этот wp_bootstrap_navwalker косячит, со вчерашнего вечера с ними воюю так ни к чему и не пришел.

Comment: Попробуй через JQuery $(document).ready(function(){}

Comment: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker вот эту фишку для меню использую, вот почему-то при добавлении пустой ссылки с title divider из редактора меню в админке этот волкер не добавляет вместо ссылки просто li  с классом divider, вот я и начал искать костыли. Почему js не срабатывает я хз, хотя на ститическую сраницу срабатывают замечательно оба кода.

Comment: @seledkapod может это поможет: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611803/bootstrap-wordpress-navwalker-top-level-nav-links-not-working

Comment: это немного не то, там ссылки в меню не правильно добавляли, оттого и проблема такая возникла. У меня же эта часть работает на ура, а вот именно `if ( strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'divider' ) == 0 && $depth === 1 ) {
   $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';` вот эта часть не хочет работать.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    o = document.querySelector('a[title="divider"]');
    o.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
    o.remove();
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-primary-1" class="nav navbar-nav center">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6">
        <a href="/" title="Главная">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8">
        <a href="#" title="divider">divider</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-7 active">
        <a href="http://test2/2016/07/24/page/" title="page">page</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Не работает, ни ссылка не удаляется, ни класс не добавляется(

Comment: @seledkapod, [fuckingimage.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2lwyd.png)

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/3axPW

Comment: @seledkapod, В сниппете здесь всё работает ведь?

Comment: мне надо чтобы на вордпрессе работало(

Comment: @seledkapod, консоль хоть что-нибудь говорит?

Comment: `@Doofy` нет, все абсолютно чисто(